# CSS : Reduce distance between last two columns in Table

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Here is the data I want to display : 
[image] 
I want to reduce the distance between last two columns, under the header *Critical PS*. I used the native HTML table element for this. I also used the border spacing and nth-child of td, but it is not working. And here is what I have done so far.
The react component:

```
<table id='aoi-table'>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th colSpan={2}>Critical PS</th>
        </tr>

        {cityData.map((item) => {
          return (
            <tr onClick={() => dispatch(addArea(item))}>
              <td>{item.name}</td>
              <td>
                <div className='status'>
                  {(() => {
                    if (item.status === "Safe") {
                      return <Dot color='#24A148' className='status-dot' />;
                    }
                    if (item.status === "Observe") {
                      return <Dot color='#F1C21B' className='status-dot' />;
                    }
                    if (item.status === "Critical") {
                      return <Dot color='#DA1E28' className='status-dot' />;
                    }
                  })()}

                  <div className='status-line'>{item.status}</div>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div className='aoi-critical-value-wrapper'>
                  {item.critical}
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                {(() => {
                  if (item.criticalValue > 0) {
                    return (
                      <div className='aoi-critical-value-positive'>
                        <UpArrowAlt className='icon-arrow' />
                        {item.criticalValue.toString()}
                      </div>
                    );
                  } else if (item.criticalValue < 0) {
                    return (
                      <div className='aoi-critical-value-negative'>
                        <DownArrowAlt className='icon-arrow' />
                        {item.criticalValue.toString().substring(1)}
                      </div>
                    );
                  } else {
                    return (
                      <div className='aoi-critical-value-neutral'>
                        {"-"}
                        {item.criticalValue}
                      </div>
                    );
                  }
                })()}
              </td>
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </table>
```

The css that I have wrote:

```css
/*there is gap between the headers, this is to remove the gap.*/
#aoi-table {
  border-spacing: 0px;
}

#aoi-table th {
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #21272a;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: none;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#aoi-table {
  width: 100%;
}

#aoi-table td {
  padding: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* not working.*/
#aoi-table tr td:nth-child(3) {
  border-spacing: 10px;
}
```

Here is what I have done so far:
[image] 
As you can see it is properly aligned. I just want to reduce the gap between the last two columns under the header Critical PS. I have used nth-child to reduce the border spacing, but it is not quite working. Please give me any suggestion.

Comment: Have you tried text-align right on the third child tds?

Comment: text-align left right doesn't work

Comment: Did you try text-align: right? (I don't understand what the left was in your comment).

Comment: I mean I tried the text-align options such left,right etc. But doesn't work.

Comment: I don't understand why that made no difference. I have put up a simple snippet in an answer so you can compare that with the actual HTML that you have to see what the difference is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example of the third td element changing to have text-align: right.

It gives the appearance of closing the gap between the 3rd and 4th columns, though of course the columns remain as they were, just the content of the third column moved to the right.

```css
#aoi-table tr td:nth-child(3) {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<table id="aoi-table">
  <tr>
    <th>h1</th>
    <th>h2</th>
    <th colspan="2">heading</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: sorry this actually worked. Why it didn't worked the first time is because there was a div inside the td. I changed the text align inside it and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I would reduce the padding of your ccs element which I am unable to identify in the CCS file provided.